# how to count mysql records for each month of the year grouped by one field

Tags: php, mysql

I has been reviewing some exmaples, but I didn't found what I need.
It's a query that show the count of record for each agency grouped by month.
Here is part of my table structure:

```
recid | agency_id | departure_date
```

So I need to count "recid" group by Agency and Month (of the departure_date) and get total colum

```
  Agency_id  | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | ........ | TOTAL 

      10        100  80    100   120   100    1200
```

It seems very easy. but I cannont find the solution.
Any help will be appreciate !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT agency_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(departure_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(departure_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(departure_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Mar,
       ...
       COUNT(*) Total
  FROM table1
 WHERE departure_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
 GROUP BY agency_id
```

Output:

```
| AGENCY_ID | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC | TOTAL |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     3 |
|         2 |   2 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     5 |
|         3 |   0 |   0 |   2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     2 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b673a/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 select agency_id, 
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 1,1,0)) as 'JAN',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 2,1,0)) as 'FEB',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 3,1,0)) as 'MAR',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 4,1,0)) as 'APR',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 5,1,0)) as 'MAY',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 6,1,0)) as 'JUN',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 7,1,0)) as 'JULY',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 8,1,0)) as 'AUG',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 9,1,0)) as 'SEPT',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 10,1,0)) as 'OCT',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 11,1,0)) as 'NOV',
    sum(if(month(`departure_date`) = 12,1,0)) as 'DEC',
            count(agency_id) as TOTAL 
 from tablename
 where .....
 group by agency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
    agency_id,
    SUM(IF(month = 1, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'January',
    SUM(IF(month = 2, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'Feburary',
    SUM(IF(month = 3, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'March',
    SUM(IF(month = 4, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'April',
    SUM(IF(month = 5, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'May',
    SUM(IF(month = 6, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'June',
    SUM(IF(month = 7, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'July',
    SUM(IF(month = 8, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'August',
    SUM(IF(month = 9, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'September',
    SUM(IF(month = 10, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'October',
    SUM(IF(month = 11, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'November',
    SUM(IF(month = 12, numRecords, NULL)) AS 'December',
    SUM(numRecords) AS total
    FROM (
        SELECT agency_id, month(departure_date) AS month, count(*) as numRecords
        FROM your_table_name
        GROUP BY agency_id, month
    ) AS SubTable1 GROUP BY agency_id
```

For the months where no record exists for a particular agency_id, this query will displaye `null`. If you want to display it as `0`, update the query and replace the `NULL` with a literal `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution with ROLLUP clause, it show what you need, but gives another output -

```
SELECT
  agency_id, MONTH(departure_date) month, COUNT(*) count
FROM
  sales
GROUP BY
  agency_id, MONTH(departure_date) WITH ROLLUP
WHERE
  YEAR(departure_date) = 2013
```